# find ZonedDateTime is today, yesterday or else

Tags: kotlin, date, date-format, java-time, zoneddatetime

I have a list of ZonedDateTime objects `(Eg. 2023-01-01T20:40:01.001+05:30[Asia/Kolkata])`

I need to write a method to get the below results.

```
if ZonedDateTime is today -> return "Today"
if ZonedDateTime is yesterday -> return "Yesterday"
else -> return ZonedDateTime in "yyyy-MM-dd" format -> (Eg. DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(zonedDateTime))
```

How can I calculate if ZonedDateTime is today, tomorrow or else? "Today" as seen in the same timezone as `ZonedDateTime` object.

Comment: "Is today" in which timezone? There are two equally reasonable choices here... - the system timezone, or the zoned date time's own timezone

Comment: @Sweeper same timezone as ZonedDateTime object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need to work with `ZonedDateTime`s for the most part. Just find out what day today is in the desired `ZoneId`, and then work with `LocalDate`s from that point onwards.

Check if `toLocalDate()` is equal to today, or if it is equal to today minus one day.

```
public static String getRelativeDateString(ZonedDateTime zdt) {
    var today = LocalDate.now(zdt.getZone());
    var ld = zdt.toLocalDate();

    if (ld.equals(today)) {
        return "Today";
    } else if (ld.equals(today.minusDays(1))) {
        return "Yesterday";
    } else {
        return ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE /* or another formatter */);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the desired format, you can simply return `ld.toString()`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I know, but my habit is to only use that as a debugging tool and always use `format(DateTimeFormatter)` for display, as the latter is more convenient to switch to a different format or use a different locale, and just more versatile in general.